# Hide elements by click by data-attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to do some filter by jQuery
This is my HTML

```
<ul id="filters" class="filter nav nav-pills">
      <li><a class="filter_link" href="#" data-category="7">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a class="filter_link" href="#" data-category="8">Portal</a></li>
      <li><a class="filter_link" href="#" data-category="9">Website</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="col-lg-3 filter_div" data-postcat="9">
   some html
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 filter_div" data-postcat="8">
   some html
</div>
```

and this is my JS

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.filter_link', function() {
    var catId = jQuery(this).data("category");
    jQuery('.filter_div').each(function(i, el) {
        var termId = jQuery(el).data('postcat');

    });
});
```

i can`t understand how i can hide and show elements by click 
if i click on ul > li > a with attribute for example 8. i want hide all divs with data-category not 8

Comment: Use `.attr("data-category")`instead of `.data("category")`

Comment: with .data in alert(catId) i see my current number. I `am interesting how hide DIVs with this number in data-postcat=catId

Comment: [is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/0vwbhwtr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.filter_link', function() {
    var catId = jQuery(this).data("category");
    //use attribute selector to find the items to be shown
    var $targets = jQuery('.filter_div[data-postcat="'+catId+'"]').show();
    //hide all the other items
    jQuery('.filter_div').not($targets).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/onovz185/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.filter_link', function() {
    var catId = $(this).data("category");
     //hide all div
    $('.filter_div').hide();
    //show only specific div
    $(".filter_div[data-postcat='" + catId +"']").show();

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61k2q4m5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the list using the [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

JavaScript

```
function showCategory(categoryId) {
    var $allDivs = jQuery('.filter_div[data-postcat]');
    var $selectedDiv = $allDivs.filter('[data-postcat='+categoryId+']');

    $allDivs.hide();
    $selectedDiv.show();
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '.filter_link', function(event) {
    var categoryId = event.target.getAttribute('data-category');

    showCategory(categoryId);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
      <li><a class="filter_link" href="#" data-category="7">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a class="filter_link" href="#" data-category="8">Portal</a></li>
      <li><a class="filter_link" href="#" data-category="9">Website</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="filter_div" data-postcat="9">
   category 9
</div>

<div class="filter_div" data-postcat="8">
   category 8
</div>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/e04kxbhc/